# How can I access "xmlns:" attributes in an XSL for-each tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the XML

```
<schema a="a" something:b="b" xmlns:c="c"/>
```

and the XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/schema/@*"> <!-- HERE ! -->
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></name>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of the transformation is:

```
<name>a</name><value>a</value>
<name>something:b</name><value>b</value>
<!-- "xmlns:c" is missing -->
```

I expected to see all attributes, but "xmlns:c" is missing. I do understand that "xmlns" is special, though, I need to access this attribute.

Is there a way to access all attributes from all namespaces, including "xmlns"?

Comment: A namespace declaration is not an attribute. You can select all namespaces in scope for the current node by `namespace::*`. -- The XML you show is not well-formed: the prefix `something`must be bound to a namespace.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. You could post it as an answer, maybe it helps somebody else.